# Can I change the type of a property in a class extension?

Tags: objective-c, clang

I wish to expose a property with a generic type in a public header, and then change its type to a more specific one in a private header. I'm using Clang, but though I'm able to change its read/write property, it doesn't accept a different type. So far this is what I tried:

A common client would import `BKSystem.h`:

```
@interface BKSystem : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, readonly) id<XYZWorker> worker;

@end
```

While a client for testing has access to internals by importing `BKSystem+Testing.h`:

```
#import "BKSystem.h"

@interface BKConfigurableWorker : NSObject<XYZWorker>

@property(nonatomic) BKConfiguration *config;

@end

#pragma mark -

@interface BKSystem ()

// Attempts to change worker to be writable and with a more specific type.
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) BKConfigurableWorker *worker;

@end
```

But on a testing client this is what I get:

```
#import "BKSystem+Testing.h"

BKSystem *system = [[BKSystem alloc] init];

// I am able to write to this property.
system.worker = [[BKConfigurableWorker alloc] init];

// ERROR: Property 'config' not found on object of type 'id<XYZWorker>'
system.worker.config = [[BKConfiguration alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you're trying to do, I'd use `BKWorker` as a subclass rather than a protocol. See my example header file below:

```
@interface BKConfiguration : NSObject

@end

@interface BKWorker : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) BKConfiguration *config;

@end


@interface BKConfigurableWorker : BKWorker

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) BKConfiguration *config;

@end
```

Notice that the same property is declared again in the configurable worker, but as `readwrite` rather than `readonly`.

This produces the following results when used in an implementation:

[image: example]

Notice how the configurable worker can be written to but the standard one can not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't control the protocol, it's defined on a library that I have to conform to. I'll update the question to make it clear.

Comment: Try explicitly declaring your config property as `readwrite` as I have done.